TypeError: browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext is not a function
TypeError: browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext is not a function
    at Object.constructFunctionParameters (file:///opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/zcatalyst-cli/lib/serve/server/lib/node/server/browserlogic/browserlogic-puppeteer.js:10:35)
    at async Server.browserLogicHandler (file:///opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/zcatalyst-cli/lib/serve/server/lib/node/server/index.js:51:20)

I'm creating a remote browser my work case. But I facing this issue. I checked with versions 19 to 22. Still facing this issue.
Anyone can be solve this issue in puppeteer?

Without knowing what code is throwing this error, it is very difficult to know how and what is throwing error. Please add the code snippet that is throwing error.

browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext has been removed from the API. The solution is not to use it. What are you actually trying to accomplish? Please provide context and share a [mcve].

Use createBrowserContext instead of createIncognitoBrowserContext (same functionality, new name).
